# Paste quoted elements into Excel without loosing quotes

Tags: microsoft-excel, copy-paste

I'm trying to copy three lines of quoted words into Excel.

[image: Things to copy]

But when I paste them the quotes are automatically deleted!

[image: auto-deleted]

Does anyone know how to keep the quotation marks on Excel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you paste the data in, you should see a clipboard icon as shown in your screenshot. Click on that and select "Use text import wizard".

Click "Next" and in step 2 of 3, select "Text qualifier" drop-down and choose "{none}" rather than the default which is quote marks).

Click Finish and it should paste your text in with quotes intact instead of them being removed.

[image: Step 2 of 3 of text import wizard in Excel]

Comment: nice answer, never spotted this before

Answer (score 1):

Before you paste the text into a cell type `'` or `"`

(will depend on your settings for which one works but I'm guessing it will be `"`)